# Em que situações usar cada tipo de prototype em elementos HTML?

Tags: javascript, protótipo

Em "protótipos" já usei várias vezes o `Element.prototype` e o `HTMLElement.prototype`. Queria saber o que é cada um e qual a diferença entre eles em exemplo, se possível. Pois em algums testes, como estes, tive o mesmo resultado:

```
HTMLElement.prototype.tooltip(); // funciona com um elemento normalmente

Element.prototype.tooltip(); // funciona com o mesmo elemento normalmente
```

Alguém poderia me mostrar a diferença prática entre os dois, caso não algum conceito ou especificação.

Outra dúvida que é enquanto ao `NodeList.prototype`, sei até o momento que posso usá-lo para, por exemplo, o `document.querySelectorAll('elemento')`. Mas creio que teria que usar um `forEach` e aplicar um `prototype` já existente, assim:

```
HTMLElement.prototype.tooltip = function(){
    ...
}
NodeList.prototype.tooltip = function(){
  [].forEach.call(NodeList, function(el){ // O NodeList dessa Linha, como usá-lo?
    el.tooltip() // tooltip já criado para elementos em particulares
  })
}
```

No `forEach` estou tentando usar o `NodeList` como um Array, poderia usar também o `Array.from()`, mas o que passo como parâmetro ao invés do "NodeList", o `this` não funciona...

Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Você já tem a resposta, eu só queria apontar que geralmente estender esse tipo de protótipo não é recomendado, devido a particularidades de sua implementação e à possibilidade de colisões com propriedades que podem ser acrescentadas à especificação no futuro. Detalhes em http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/.

Comment: @bfavaretto, apenas comecei a ler pois estou um pouco ocupado... mas já dando uma olhada superfial geral, achei bem interessante.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Samir, `Element` representa qual quer elemento no Documento, seja texto, html, svg, xml, etc.

O HtmlElement representa apenas os elementos HTML, como por exemplo uma `<div>`, `<input>`, elementos como `<svg>` implementam a interface `SVGElement`.

Desta forma, `HtmlElement` tem como Base `Element`, então qual quer inclusão no prototype de `Element` irá refletir em todas as interfaces que tem `Element` como base, tais como `HTMLElement` e `SVGelement`.

Note que `Element` por sua vez tem como base a interface `Node` e `NodeList` é uma coleção de `Node`. Se deseja que apenas os `HTMLElement` sejam afetados, então faça o seguinte:

```js
NodeList.prototype.forEach = function (callback) {
  var indice = 0;
  [].forEach.call(this, function (element) {
    if (element instanceof HTMLElement) {
      callback(element, indice);
      indice++;
    }
  });
};

var blocos = document.querySelectorAll(".bloco");
blocos.forEach(function (element, indice) {
 console.log(element, indice);
});
```

```html
<div class="bloco"></div>
<div class="bloco"></div>
<div class="bloco"></div>
<svg class="bloco"></svg>
<div class="bloco"></div>
```

Agora o mesmo código sem a verificação do tipo do Elemento.

```js
NodeList.prototype.forEach = function (callback) {
  [].forEach.call(this, function (element, indice) {
    callback(element, indice);
  });
};

var blocos = document.querySelectorAll(".bloco");
blocos.forEach(function (element, indice) {
 console.log(element, indice);
});
```

```html
<div class="bloco"></div>
<div class="bloco"></div>
<div class="bloco"></div>
<svg class="bloco"></svg>
<div class="bloco"></div>
```

Se deseja que o `tooltip()` não possa ser aplicado sobre um `<svg>`, então use `HTMLElement.prototype`, caso contrario use `Element.prototype`

Comment: TobyMosque, muito obrigado por sua resposta, tirou até outra dúvida minha...

Comment: @SamirBraga, qual seria a outra duvida?

Comment: Era a questão do `this` no NodeList.. Mas possuo ainda outra dúvida, mas não sei se é o caso de postar outra pergunta. Por exemplo, no tooltip que criei, ele pode ou não receber um objeto como argumento, se sim, será estilizado, caso não receberá o css, padrão. Porém quando uso o nodelist isso não funciona...

Comment: Opa.. Problema resolvido, tenho nem como explicar.. era algo muio específico, mas agora está funcionando.. Obrigado..

Comment: Toby, vale o alerta que deixei [lá em cima](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/108511/em-que-situa%c3%a7%c3%b5es-usar-cada-tipo-de-prototype-em-elementos-html#comment224247_108511) ;)

Comment: @bfavaretto, valeu pelo alerta, em particularmente prefiro criar uma "Classe" que receba o HTMLElement, no caso eu faria `var ToopTip = function(element) { ... };`, mas isto já é uma questão de preferencia.

Comment: Também acho que embalar o objeto nativo em outro é a melhor maneira de resolver.